# Creating a Graph Webhook Subscription, why am I getting this message? "Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter"

Tags: asp.net, graph, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to Graph. I'm attempting to subscribe to changes in /users. Here's my Headers and POST to Graph:

```
//HTTP POST
//Host: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
//Content-Type:applicaton/json
//Authorization: {auth key}
{
"changeType":"updated"
,"clientState":"myClientState"
,"resource":"/users"
,"notificationUrl":"[ngrok URL tunneling back to my local debug api instance]"
,"expirationDateTime":"2020-05-23T04:30:28.2257768+00:00"
}
```

And this is the relevant code on my core web API that gets the response from Graph:

```
// POST api/values
        public IHttpActionResult Post ([FromUri]string validationToken)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("validationToken string is: " + validationToken);


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken))
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("Token received, sending back token: " + validationToken);

                return Ok(validationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                //...
            }
    }
```

I've tested this by hitting it up via Postman and it sends back exactly whatever query parameter it receives, as expected. When I send the POST call to Graph, my Web API gets the response. It has one parameter:

```
key: validationToken
value: 'Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: ea95e0a8-55c6-42db-b7e6-441920ae9c15'
```

So that's what I send back. I always get this error after:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ea95e0a8-55c6-42db-b7e6-441920ae9c15",
      "date": "2020-05-18T20:07:17"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried different encodings and confirmed that my Auth token is valid, and all endpoints are reaching each other OK. Honestly that doesn't really look like what I expect a validation token to look like - is that even it? I see nothing else in the POST body and there's no other params. Here's the exact request URI with the query parameter included:

```
https://localhost:44391/api/values?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+ea95e0a8-55c6-42db-b7e6-441920ae9c15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure validation token is returned as plain/text content-type. EG:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri] string validationToken) {
    Debug.WriteLine("validationToken string is: " + validationToken);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken)) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Token received, sending back token: " + validationToken);

        return this.ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            Content = new StringContent(validationToken)
        });
    }
    else {
        return this.InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `return Ok(validationToken);` by `return Content(validationToken);`.

Ok expects the parameter to be an object and might wrap what is passed in with JSON or XML depending on the request and the pipeline configuration.

Content expects the parameter to be a string and returns it as is.
You can use the [postman collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation) to validate your endpoint's validation implementation and look at the [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample) for more information.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. I don't have a Content() function, but restructuring the code to  ensure I only return a string did the trick. What's odd is that I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fThiCZmIcMQ&feature=emb_title) and he uses return Ok()

Comment: it might be an addition for asp.net core 3 hence why you don't have it and why it's not in the video